# What is the meaning of 'cast a bank'?

Tags: graham-hancock, the-bible, the-sign-and-the-seal

To ask I need a quote

> "Thus saith the Lord concerning the kind of Assyria, He shall not come into this city, nor shoot an arrow there, nor come before it with shields, nor cast a bank against it ... For I will defend this city to save it for mine own sake."

```
Isaiah 37:33, 35
```

quoted in "The Sign And The Seal" by Graham Hancock.

What is the meaning of the phrase 'nor cast a bank against it'? I ran some Google searches on "cast a bank" and all led me to the same paragraph. Is some kind of wall-breaking weapon or device meant here?

Comment: I assume the phrase means "building siegeworks".  "Cast" usually means "throw" but can mean "make" or "build".  I imagine Mesopotamian sieges  involved building earth ramps against the city's walls, as described and illustrated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Lachish) (but not very clearly).

Comment: See also "The Assyrian Siege Ramp at Lachish: Military and Lexical Aspects" by  Israel Eph'al, in *Journal of the Institute of Archaeology of Tel Aviv University*,  Volume 11, 1984 - Issue 1 (http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1179/tav.1984.1984.1.60?journalCode=ytav20) if you can.

Comment: Only two occurrences of "make a bank" usage found on the Internet are nevertheless backups your idea. One of them is (to me more convincing)
"In the same paragraph, the owner has to make a bank against the river from the Gage to a close called West Croft and it is to be 20ft in breadth and 'sufficient in height"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### "cast a bank" means to build a ramp.

This is the archaic meaning of "cast" as in item 1, subitem 9 [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cast#Verb):

> (archaic) To throw up, as a mound, or rampart.
>
> - Bible, Luke xix.48
>
>   > Thine enemies shall cast a trench [bank] about thee.

And the meaning of "bank" as in a bank *of* something, as in item 2 [here](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bank):

> A long, high mass or mound of a particular substance.
>
> > ‘a grassy bank’
> >     ‘a bank of snow’

Finally, this interpretation of the quote is confirmed by other versions (translations) of this specific biblical passage:

- > He will not enter this city
  >   or shoot an arrow here.
  >   He will not come before it with shield
  >   or **build a siege ramp against it**.
  >
  > <sub>-- [New International Version](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah+37%3A33-37&version=NIV) (emphasis mine)</sub>
- > propterea haec dicit Dominus de rege Assyriorum non introibit civitatem hanc et non iaciet ibi sagittam et non occupabit eam clypeus et **non mittet in circuitu eius aggerem**
  >
  > <sub>-- [Vulgate Latin version](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah+37%3A33-37&version=VULGATE) (emphasis mine; [mittet](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mittet) is a form of [mitto](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mitto#Latin), roughly meaning to extend, and [aggerem](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aggerem) is a form of [agger](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/agger#Latin), meaning a rampart or dyke)</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and for the link to the dictionary en.wiktionary.org. I'm obsessed with having many dictionaries and looking difficult words in all of them.

Comment: @VladimirZolotykh Wiktionary has a *lot* of different words, in many languages. One caveat though: like Wikipedia, it's user-editable, so it may not always be as reliable as, say, Oxford Dictionaries.